# How to correctly query to a Foreign Key in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have a group of models `Cluster`, `Server` and `Service` which have a relationship, through a ForeignKey, one-to-many, as the following snippet:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    .
    .
    .


class Service(models.Model):
    host_server = models.ForeignKey(Server, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    .
    .
    .
```

And now I am trying to get a set of `Servers` in a query, along with the related `Services` using

```
def infra(request, cluster_name):

    cluster = Cluster.objects.get(name__iexact=cluster_name)
    servers = Server.objects.filter(cluster_id=cluster.id).order_by('shortname')
    services = Service.objects.filter(host_server__in=servers).order_by('id')

    template = 'webapp/infra.html'
    context = {
        'cluster':cluster,
        'servers':servers,
        'services':services,
        }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

However, on the view, I am getting **all the services** in a single QuerySet instead of a QuerySet per `Server` containing only the `Services` associated with it.

As a workaround to this, I used the following:

```
<h5>Services</h5>
  <ul class="list-group">
    {% for service in services %}
      {% if service.host_server_id == server.id %}
        <li class="list-group-item">{{ service.name }}</li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

But I have the feeling that there must be a way to iterate through the services of each server in a more elegant way than going through absolutely all of the services each time and then deciding if it should de displayed or not.

Is it possible to improve or is this initial approach right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a related_name for your `host_server` field and make use of [Django's Reverse ForeignKey Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) to get associated services for each server.

*NB: without `related_name`, the reverse manager would be accessible from `service_set`*

*models.py*

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    host_server = models.ForeignKey(Server, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="services")
```

*views.py*

```py
def infra(request, cluster_name):

    cluster = Cluster.objects.get(name__iexact=cluster_name)
    # we use `prefetch_related` to speedup the query
    servers = Server.objects.filter(cluster_id=cluster.id).prefetch_related('services').order_by('shortname')
    return render(request, 'webapp/infra.html', {
        'cluster':cluster,
        'servers':servers,
    })
```

*infra.html*

```html
  <ul class="list-group">
    {% for server in servers %}
      <li class="list-group-item">{{ server.name }}
        <ul>
        {% for service in server.services.all %}
          <li class="list-item">{{ service.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely what I was trying to achieve. I even went through the reference you mentioned, but the example wasn't as clear as yours.